# Updating two fields in a table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a List and will like to update two fields in a table.
The two fields are CustOrderNumber and CustomerRefnumber using the CatId
to identify the row.

How can I update these two fields based on their Id such that it will be efficient?

Here is the model

```
            public class Catalog
            {
                public Int32 CatId { get; set; }
                public string Ischecked { get; set; }
                public string CustOrderNumber { get; set; }
                public string CustomerRefnumber { get; set; }
            }
```

Here is the method that will handle the collection

```
            public List<Catalog> WriteToDB(List<Catalog> objCat)
            {
                DataCollectEntities _objDataCollect = new DataCollectEntities();

                foreach( var item in objcat)
                {


                }

            }
```

Comment: Inside your loop do this `var obj = _objDataCollect.Catalog.Where(x => x.CatId == item.CatId).Single()` and then update this `obj` with new  values like `obj.CustOrderNumber= item.CustOrderNumber` same for other property... Then out side loop write `_objDataCollect.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Catalog 's from the db for those items passed to your method. Update the property value of each item and save it back.

```
public List<Catalog> WriteToDB(List<Catalog> objCat)
{
    var ids = objCat.Select(s=>s.CatId);

    var db = new DataCollectEntities();
    var catalogList= db.Catalogs.Where(s=>ids.Contains(s.CatId)).ToList();

    foreach( var item in catalogList)
    {
      var c= objCat.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.CatId==item.Id);
      if(c!=null)
      {
        item.CustomerRefnumber = c.CustomerRefnumber;
        item.CustOrderNumber = c.CustOrderNumber ;
      }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Number of SQL queries executed ?**

**1** select statement for getting the catalogs from the db.

**N** update statement(s) for updating each record where `N` is the number of records(Catalogs) you want to update

So if you are trying to update 3 catalogs, This code will hit the db **1 + 3 =4** times.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying this is more efficient. I might have about 150 rows to update. Does that mean I will hit the database 150 times?

Comment: ObjCat is the new List I want to use to update the database

Comment: You can use old school( but best performance) ADO.NET to execute a  huge UPDATE statement for all the records. There might be alimit for the SQL string to pass. So you may need to split your N records into few batches and execute it. The dbContext has a `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` method you may use if you prefer that.